# Opening an encoded file with PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii, strpos

I am opening a file on the server with PHP.  The file seems ordinary.  It opens in Notepad and Textedit on a PC.  Even PHP can display it without any issue in a web browser when we echo out.

But when I try searching it with strpos() it can’t find anything except single characters.  if i search for a string with 2 or more characters, it doesn’t find anything.

I have tried encoding it to UTF-8, and it detects it as ASCII.  so everything seems right there.

I have also isolated the part of the file that I am trying to read down to only 250 characters.  They all look fine on the screen.

But strpos can’t find it. I’ve run tests on every part of my code and I believe everything is fine with my code.  The problem I believe derives from that the characters I see on the screen are not exactly matching what those characters really are.

My last resort is to write a function which converts each character into an integer array (if that’s even possible), and then convert all that  back to a string.  This way, we’ll know 100% that the characters we see are real.

Hoping that somebody has a better approach or perhaps an idea for something I missed?

I'll post the code below:

```
 $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());  // get the file contents
 $content = substr($content, 30, 300);  // reduce the large file to just the first few lines
 $content = htmlspecialchars($content);  // try to remove any special characters from the file

$content = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $content);  // encode to a friendly format

$string = "JobName";  // this is the string i'm searching for

if (strpos($content, $string) !== false) {
echo "bingo";
}

else {
echo " not found ";
}
```

Just to be clear, the file I'm opening is generated from a PC program that stores its data in .DAT format. Like I said, I can see and read the content very easily using any program, including PHP. but when I try to search, its as if it doesn't recognize the content at all.

I am not aware of how to upload a file on StackOverflow, but if someone can tell me how to do it then I will gladly post the file itself.

Comment: Simply use a "hexeditor" to examine that file, check what characters are really used in there.

Comment: Please do _not_ add details in comments. There is an `edit` link for tha below your question. _Use it_.

Comment: Can you provide this file?

Comment: or at least the first 400 characters of it

Comment: And who upvotes questions like this. It is unanswerable as it stands without even a clue about what the file looks like. _Please dont UV without good reason. You are not fooling anyone worth fooling__

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help ARKASCHA.  I was able to find an online HexEditor and when I saw the characters, it seems there is a NUL character between every single character in this file.  that's probably why I couldn't see it with a regular view.  I just had to run an additional function to remove NUL characters from the file, and then it works as its supposed.  Thanks again.